# How do I do set /a on Wine CMD?

Tags: wine

How do I use the `set /a` command on the Wine version of CMD?

This doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
set /a option=1+1
echo %option%
```

On a Windows computer it would output 2 on the screen but in the Wine version it just outputs whether Echo is on or not.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can someone like please answer the question

Answer (score 1):

"set /a" was not implemented in cmd until WINE 1.5.20

Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you may be able to work around this by doing the math with a bash script that outputs to a text file, then assigning the contents of the file to a variable from inside WINE like so:

```
set /p option=<file.txt
```